# intl.formatMessage not working - react-intl

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-intl, babel-plugin-react-intl

I am trying to do language translation using `react-intl`. When I use this `<FormattedMessage id='importantNews' />`, it is working perfect. But when I use the following code with `intl.formatMessage()`, it is not working and throwing some errors. I don't know what is wrong in it.

```
import { injectIntl, FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';

function HelloWorld(props) {
  const { intl } = props;
  const x = intl.formatMessage('hello') + ' ' + intl.formatMessage('world'); //not working
  const y = <FormattedMessage id='hello' />; //working
  return (
    <button>{x}</button>
  );
}

export default injectIntl(HelloWorld);
```

My root component is like this,

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { addLocaleData, IntlProvider } from 'react-intl';
import enLocaleData from 'react-intl/locale-data/en';
import taLocaleData from 'react-intl/locale-data/ta';

import HelloWorld from './hello-world';

addLocaleData([
  ...enLocaleData,
  ...taLocaleData
]);

const messages = {
  en: {
    hello: 'Hello',
    world: 'World'
  },
  ta: {
    hello: 'வணக்கம்',
    world: 'உலகம்'
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <IntlProvider key={'en'} locale={'en'} messages={messages['en']}>
    <HelloWorld />
  </IntlProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check props correctly passed or not.

Comment: I hope I am passing props correctly. Can you tell me which props you are saying?

Comment: Intl props. And Can you explain what are the errors you got?

Comment: I don't know about intl props. But I am getting this error `Uncaught Error: [React Intl] An 'id' must be provided to format a message.`

Comment: Are you a Tamizan. I am a Tamizan. I don't know about it. I'll refer and share my knowledge.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to call [`formatMessage`](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#formatmessage) with [`MessageDescriptor`](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#definemessages), not just `id`:

```
const x = intl.formatMessage({id: 'hello'}) + ' ' + intl.formatMessage({id: 'world'});
```

---

To better remember this - component is called with prop `id`:

```
<FormatMessage id="Hello" />
```

Props are in fact a key-value dictionary:

```
// this is the same as above
<FormatMessage {...{id: 'hello'}} />
```

Now, `formatMessage` function accepts the same props as `FormatMessage` component:

```
formatMessage({id: 'hello'})
```

Comment: Tomas, your solution worked actually. I did put yesterday's code in some other file and it throwed me error today also. Sorry about that. Your answer with explanation is more clearer. Thanks a lot! I will delete my previous comment over time.

Answer (score 3):

After trying and failing with dynamic values, I figured out that if `const intlKey = "something"`

```
{intl.formatMessage({ id: intlKey })} //this doesn't work
{intl.formatMessage({ id: `${intlKey}` })} //this works
```

```
<IntlMessages id={intlKey} /> //this doesn't work
<IntlMessages id={`${intlKey}`} /> //this works
```

Thus stringify your value (even if sure that it's a string) for intl to work.

Comment: Only this could help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Besides, seems like you are missing default value for it.

```
 <FormattedMessage id="footer.table_no" defaultMessage="Hello" />
```